# Order of initialization in java, inheritance and overrride fields

Tags: java, inheritance, initialization, overriding

```java
class A {
    static int c = 7;
    int a = 0;

    public A() {
        c = c + 2;
        a = c;
    }

    public int m(int x){
        return a * --x;
    }

}


class B extends A{
    int a = 13;
    static int c = 1;
    public B(){
        c = c*3;
        a = c;

    }

    public int m (int x){
        return --a * ++x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A o1 = new A();
        A o2 = new B();
        B o3 = new B();

        System.out.println(o1.a);
        System.out.println(o1.m(o1.a));
        System.out.println(o1.a);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(o2.a);
        System.out.println(o2.m(5));
        System.out.println(o2.a);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(o3.a);

    }
}
```

I know about dynamic and static binding, but I don't understand how it works in this example(with overriding static fields). I am really surprised why o2.m = 12, and o3.a = 9! Is c field separate for these classes? Which fields are using in B constructor? Is difference if i wrote A o1 = new B() or B o1 = new B()? Please explain how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is difference if i wrote `A o1 = new B()` or `B o1 = new B()`?** .

Yes,

```
A o1 = new B(); calls methods of `B` and fields of A.
B o1 = new B(); calls methods of `B` and fields of B.
```

i.e, field references are resolved based on reference type and method calls are resolved (dynamically) based on object type.

Comment: So why in this example  A o2 = new B(); o2.m(5) = 12? It looks like field a was from 'B'

Comment: @xorgx3 - Well, the method `m()` is from `B`. So, it uses a and x from b. after the `B` object is constructed, your a will be equal to c (which will be 3). So, --a * ++x will be (3-1) * (5+1) => 2*6=12

Comment: But i have one more problem. I have two times  System.out.println(c); From which class this field will be printed?

Comment: `c` is a static field. The value of `c` from the current context (B) will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that in the way you define it, B has 2 members that are called `a`. Consider this:

add methods to class B as follows:

```
public int x() {
    return this.a;
}
public int y() {
    return super.a;
}
```

If you then do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();

    System.out.println(b.x());
    System.out.println(b.y());

}
```

Output will be:

```
3
9
```

Your definition of `a` in class B does not replace or overwrite the `a` from class A: it **hides** it. As you can see, you can still access it through calling `super`, but it does lead to unmaintainable code and is therefore discouraged.

There are several things you should do to avoid this kind of mishap:

- Do not give several fields the same name, because it will make your code less clear.
- Make your object members `private` unless you **really** have a compelling reason not to. Your example has demonstrated that even `protected` access can make things opaque in a hurry.
- Use getters and setters for the members. If your object is of type `B`, then it doesn't matter whether your object is defined as `A` or `B`.

Whether you write this:

```
A obj = new B();
obj.getA();
```

or this:

```
B obj = new B();
obj.getA();
```

won't matter for your output, because your method call will always call the getter as "low" as possible in the class hierarchy, which will always be `B` (if a method is available) because the runtime type of the object is `B`. That last bit is actually @TheLostMind 's point

Comment: Thanks for advices, but I know it :) This is example from my Java exam and I prepare to them. And still don't exactly know what it step by step works.

Comment: Tip: if you want to improve your understanding of what happens, you can add System.out.println calls to the constructors and methods to see what gets called. Or you can debug, of course.